# Is paris-studios Excel multicore processing solution legit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I was looking for ways to [make Excel use all cpu cores](http://analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-vba-multithreading-addin/) and run into this site: http://www.paris-studios.de/projekte/item/126-vba-excel-16x-core-multi-threaded-multicore-processing-architecture-solution-engine

I can't find any info on Google and I'm not brave/stupid enough to run this in my pc without knowing the source. Does anyone know if this tool is legit? The website seems [a little fishy](https://www.scamadviser.com/check-website/paris-studios.de) to me. I would like to know if anyone has used this.

[Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/es/file/e98486d255939d7148729c2d03f50ad307238c03951931c84bc41a8174e26b43/analysis/1499880444/) doesn't bring anything up.

Comment: that... actually sparked my interest. Based on my time spent with excel this looks like a cool thing to try. 

download this tool to try running the application in a secure environment. I would really like to see your results. 

https://www.sandboxie.com

Comment: company that actually made this was: https://www.liebherr.com/en/usa/about-liebherr/liebherr-worldwide/germany/lindenberg/aerospace-lindenberg.html

Comment: How do you know? :) Do you think it's safe then? I will run some test on sandboxie tomorrow, thanks for the link.

Comment: @admin, can you please take hold off? This is actually a really good question. Unless you guys always want to solve easy questions, this is exactly what this website was meant for originally.